# Перезагрузить модуль NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, reload

У меня есть файл `comp1.js`, я запускаю его `require("./comp1")`, все в порядке.
Но когда мне понадобилось перезагрузить только этот файл и выполнить действия в уже перезагруженном `require("./comp1").myfunc()` работала так, как и до изменения файла и использования `require("./comp1")`.

Comment: что значит перезагрузить?

Comment: [require.cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache)

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо, помогло